# cross platform game development using html5

Tags: javascript, android, html, graphics, cross-platform

What are the options for cross platform 3D graphics / game development for html5?

I have heard names like webgl, canvas, and css, but I can't seem to find an up to date analysis of which technologies are the best to use.

I would like to target android (ios would be a bonus) and desktop at the same time with html5.

Finally, do you know of any resources or tutorials for html5/js for what im looking to accomplish?

Comment: http://learningthreejs.com/ this website has some good tutorials related to implementing webgl and 3d for the web

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a list of [3D HTML5 Game Engines](http://mobilegameengines.com/html5/3d_game_engines) along with which platforms they support.

Have you seen Browser Quest?

It was made entirely in HTML5 and JavaScript, powered by WebSockets.

http://browserquest.mozilla.org/

http://www.littleworkshop.fr/browserquest.html

Also there is HexGL

It uses  HTML5, Javascript (three.js) and WebGL.

http://hexgl.bkcore.com/

Answer (score 0):

You could try webGL
http://www.chromeexperiments.com/webgl/
It has been used to write cool things like cube slam
http://www.chromeexperiments.com/detail/cube-slam/?f=